# Stmt и нагрузка на сервер БД?

Tags: mysqli, php

Использовал обычные запросы к БД - все ок. Только что поменял код с использованием stmt что-то типа того:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?";
        $stmt = $this->db->stmt($query,array("i",$id));
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$content,$date,$author,$visible);
        $stmt->fetch();
```

На локалке работает, на хосте вдруг вылетает  ошибка :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /mySite/model_news.php on line 31
```

31 - это как раз на строке с bind->result();

То есть не хватает какой-то памяти. Какой? Ошибка появляется даже если запрос должен возвратить совсем маленькие объемы данных.

Уважаемые программисты, в чем может быть дело? 
Не могу выявить причину, на другом сайте stmt нормально работает. Может быть, слишком много переменных?

UPDATE. Действительно, прописал вместо * только одно значение и в bind_result ввел только одну переменную - вроде бы не матюкается. Но - мне нужно 6 переменных!

Comment: Странное какое-то число - 4 гигабайта. 

Похоже на ошибку, только не в Вашем запросе, а в mysql на этом хосте.

Comment: хост платный...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед

```
 bind->result(...);
```

поставил

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Все заработало!